# Xdebug Remote Debugging inside Docker on remote server

Tags: php, docker, server, xdebug, ssh-tunnel

I need to debug PHP scripts located inside a Docker container on a remote server.

Usually, I debug my code using Visual Studio Code in Windows. I've been debugging my dev codes (which is located in a Vagrant) this way without any problem.

But when it comes to debugging files in a Docker on a remote server I couldn't get it to work.

Here's my xdebug setting on php.ini (in docker located on a remote server)

```
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_host=172.18.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/debug.log
```

The `remote_host` IP address in the setting above is the IP of the remote host seen from inside Docker.

I've tried ssh-tunneling to my remote server (from Windows, using telnet).

But when I try to run the site on my browser, my Visual Studio Code couldn't detect the debugging session.

Basically what I did are these:

1. Start a debugging session on my local machine (Windows)
2. Create ssh-tunnel to remote server (forwarding port 9000 on the server to localhost:9000) using `ssh -R 9000:localhost:9000 username@myremoteserver.com`
3. Mapped port 9000 on Docker to port 9000 on remote server
4. Xdebug in docker is set to listen to its host (so to IP address of host seen from inside docker, which I got from running this command from inside docker: `/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }'`

When I run the site, the `/tmp/debug.log` contains this:

```
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 172.18.0.1:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///magento/test.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="5.6.33-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1" protocol_version="1.0" appid="12776" idekey="www-data"><engine version="2.5.5"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2017 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>
```

How can I 'relay' the connection set by Xdebug from Docker, to my remote server, to the IDE on my local pc?

Comment: Do not use standard 9000 port -- better choose 9001 or some another. Right now some service that is aware of what Xdebug is and how it works is responding to Xdebug connection (as per your log) and simply tells Xdebug to "go away" (by saying "run without debug till the end"). It could easily be php-fpm if you are using wrong IP address. Plus, no idea where `172.18.0.1` comes from -- for SSH tunnel you should really be using `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: 1) *"Xdebug in docker is set to listen to its host"* WHAT? RTM please. Xdebug does NOT listen anything. Simply because it's Xdebug that connects to IDE and NOT other way around... 2) IP address must be the address of the PC where your IDE/editor is running (if you prefer and can connect directly). otherwise you need SSH tunnel ... and then you need to use 127.0.0.1 so connection gets forwarded from remote system to your dev PC.

Comment: 3) Right now you must be just connecting to the local (on remote) php-fpm or some similar service that is Xdebug aware (knows how it works) .. as it clearly told Xdebug to "go away".

Comment: 1) RTM: https://xdebug.org/docs/remote 2) It's for PhpStorm .. but will work for VSCode as well (as the basis is the same for any IDE/editor): https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Remote+debugging+in+PhpStorm+via+SSH+tunnel

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53496300/xdebug-php-7-1-phpstorm-remote-server-with-docker-how/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no success to do the same by ssh-tunnel :(

But it's possible by [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). You should:

1. install `ngrok` on your local development machine;
2. run `ngrok tcp 9000`;
3. set `xdebug.remote_port` and `xdebug.remote_host` according to `ngrok`'s info.