# Xdebug PHP 7.1 PhpStorm remote server with Docker. How?

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

```
Local:   
 - OS: MacOS  
 - IDE: PhpStorm   
 - Debug Port: 10000   
 - DBGp Proxy Host: 127.0.0.1   
 - DBGp Proxy Port: 10000    

Remote server:  
 - OS: Ubuntu  
 - Run project via docker and expose 10000 port    

Docker container:    
 - XDEBUG_CONFIG: "default_enable=1 remote_host=172.30.0.1 remote_enable=1 profiler_enable_trigger=0 remote_port=10000"
```

1. I enable "Listen debug connections" in PhpStorm
2. Run in terminal: ssh -R 10000:127.0.0.1:10000 root@remote-server
3. Add breakpoints
4. Run site page

> Xdebug not working:(

Xdebug log:

```
Log opened at 2018-11-27 09:05:03
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 172.30.0.1:10000.
W: Creating socket for '172.30.0.1:10000', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2018-11-27 09:05:03
```

I want connect to remote server for debbuging. I am not interested create port forwarding into docker container.

What am I doing wrong?

Screenshots:
[image: phpstorm settings]
[image: docker compose file (server part)]
[image: docker inspect server container]

Comment: Have you read : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html ?
If you need help, I advise that you give the precise config files, PhPStorm menus, etc ... rather than a summary please.

Comment: @St3an yes I read. I added some screenshots.

Comment: Why do you need DBGPoxy? It's very specific separate software .. and not needed for local development. If you are using Docker .. then stick to the Xdebug Docker tutorials ...

Comment: Right now: you are telling PhpStorm to listen on port 10000 .. and at the same time exposing the same port via Docker .... They cannot both listen on the same port.

Comment: @LazyOne this configuration work fine on local computer. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use xdebug with ssh tunnel port forwarding from remote docker-hosted server to local machine, but have no success.

But it works using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). You should:

1. install `ngrok` on your local development machine;
2. run `ngrok tcp 9000`;
3. set `xdebug.remote_port` and `xdebug.remote_host` according to `ngrok`'s info.

If somehow known how to do the same by ssh tunneling, please share it.

9000 - its xdebug client's port, 9000 - default value in PHP Storm, for this topic should be 10000.